# How to send values of selected checkboxes to a app.get route

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email, express

I have this button:

```
<a type="button" class="sendEmail" href="/email/new/">Enviar Email</a>
```

And i have multiple checkboxes with emails inside the values:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="myemail@gmail.com"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="other@gmail.com"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="your@gmail.com"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="something@gmail.com"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="nothing@gmail.com"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="stackoverflow@gmail.com"/>
```

I need send the emails to the app get -> /email/new/EMAILS

For this, i create the following code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".sendEmail").click(function() {

                var emails = [];
                var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");


                for (var i = checkboxes.length -1 ; i>= 0; i--) {
                    if (checkboxes[i].type === "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked) {
                          emails.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                    }
                }

                var link = "/email/new/" + emails;
                $(this).attr("href", link);
            });
        });
```

Is working, but.. this is the right solution? Is there anything that express help me?

Just for help u guys understand everything, this is my route:

```
app.get('/email/new/:param, function(req, res) {
  var emails = req.param("param");
  res.send(emails);
});
```

OBS: i am using the EJS to populate the values of the checkboxes throw a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using a pathParam ? Why just not use queryParam ?

It a simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".sendEmail").click(function() {

    var emails = [];
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");


    for (var i = checkboxes.length -1 ; i>= 0; i--) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type === "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked) {
            emails.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }

    var link = "/email/new?";

    for(var i = 0; i <= emails.length; i++){
        link += "emails=" + emails[i] + "&";
    }

    $(this).attr("href", link);
});
});
```

and

```
app.get('/email/new', function(req, res) {
  var emails = req.query.emails;
  res.send(emails);
});
```

Documentation -> [Express request query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

Comment: but i am using the node.js with ejs, not angular.

Comment: can u please show me some code? I need use the jquery to change the button link?

Comment: interesting solution, but there is a problem.. there is a undefined showing with the emails

Comment: the url is ?emails=myemail@something.com&emails=undefined&, and should be ?emails=myemail@something.com&otheremail@something.com, right?

Comment: add condition if == undefined then nothing